# Advanced Custom Fields, DatePicker - Check if Set

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, datepicker

I am trying an IF statement to check if the user has actually selected a value in the ACF DatePicker but this doesn't validate correctly. Any ideas?

```
$fxdate = get_field('fl_date');
if (isset($fxdate)) {echo "set";} else {echo "not set";}
```

Comment: Where do you put this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print html when custom field has value inside while loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/306675/print-html-when-custom-field-has-value-inside-while-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if echoing $fxdate is working.

$fxdate = get_field('fl_date');

In ACF simply below code works,

```
if($fxdate){ echo "set"; } else { echo "not set"; }
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me